# excel search list for item and its suffixes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to search for all instances in a list for entries which match or begin with those listed in a criteria group. Imagine a list of servers consisting of the below. Where we have a database on that server also, it is indicated with an _SQL, _ORACLE suffix:

## Column A

- VM001
- VM001_SQL
- VM002
- VM002_SQL
- VM003
- VM003_SQL
- VM0003_ORACLE
- VM004
- VM004_SQL
- VM005
- VM006

I need to search for all servers from the group below

## Column D

- VM002
- VM003

I need to be able to identify the 2 listings of VM002 and 3 listings of VM003 in the list in Column A.

I can easily search for how many times VM002 or VM003 appear in the overall list by using the function, `=COUNTIF(A:A,D1&"*")`.

What I need then is some way of indicating which servers in Col A match those of the smaller group, so I can sort, filter, etc. How can I identify entries in Col A along with their suffixes?

Comment: How do you want to identify the correct servers e.g colour code them, separate list, filtered list...?

Comment: Use conditional formatting - you already have the logic...

Comment: @Alex, if my list is in column A, what I was trying to do was add a function in column B similar to countif again: COUNTIF(D:D,A4). The tricky bit though is, if A4 contains VM002_SQL, then I want countif to mark B4 as '1', i.e. true, because it contains VM002, which is part of my list in column D... I hope I'm explaining this correctly.

Comment: Should "VM0003_ORACLE" be "VM003_ORACLE"?  Based on your comments, it looks like you slipped an extra "0" in there....

Answer (score 1):

First enter the following User Defined Function *(UDF)* in a standard module:

```
Public Function Keyword(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Variant
    v1 = r1.Text
    For Each r In r2
        If InStr(v1, r.Text) = 1 Then
            Keyword = 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
    Keyword = ""
End Function
```

Then in **B1** enter:

```
=keyword(A1,$D$1:$D$2)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

To use the UDF for a full column, use this version instead:

```
Public Function Keyword(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Variant
    v1 = r1.Text

    Set r2 = Intersect(r2, r2.Parent.UsedRange)

    For Each r In r2
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(v1, r.Text) = 1 Then
                Keyword = 1
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    Keyword = ""
End Function
```

Comment: that works great, thanks. Is there a way of getting it to run by selecting the whole of column D, e.g. =keyword(A1,D:D)? Currently it will return 1 for all entries in col A if I try this?

Comment: @Covfefe  See my **EDIT#1**